# This class should provide a default constructor

Tags: android, apk

When I am trying to generate signed apk i am obtaining this error message:

> Error:(24) Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a
>   public constructor with no arguments)
>   (es.yepwarriors.yepwarriors.adapters.UserAdapter) [Instantiatable]

In my class:

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> {
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<ParseUser> users){
        super(context, R.layout.message_item, users);
        mContext = context;
        mUsers = users;
    }
    ...
```

I add the constructor to fix the error with:

```
public UserAdapter(){
    super(null,0);
}
```

But I don´t understand what is the origin of the problem. Can you explain to me?
Thanks.

Comment: did you declare by mistake UserAdapter in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I did @Blackbelt :( I changed it and it is running! Thanks!!!

Comment: Cool, I am glad I was able to help you